# how to drag and scroll on a line

Tags: angular

what i want to do do is when dragging the rectangle left or right horizantally i scroll on my line on the same time but it doesnt work : when iclick on my rectangle to moove it right or left it does not moove this is my ts code

```
  positionX: number = 0;
  isMouseDown: boolean = false;
  initialMouseX: number = 0;
  initialPositionX: number = 0;

  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.isMouseDown = true;
    this.initialMouseX = event.clientX;
    this.initialPositionX = this.positionX;
  }

  onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.isMouseDown = false;
  }

  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.isMouseDown) {
      const containerWidth = event.target['clientWidth'];
      const mouseX = event.clientX;

      const newPositionX = this.initialPositionX + (mouseX - this.initialMouseX);
      this.positionX = Math.max(0, Math.min(containerWidth, newPositionX));
    }
  }
```

and this is the html code :

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="line">
        <div
          class="rectangle"
          [style.left.px]="positionX"
          (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
        ></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cdkDrag to drag an element into a boundary div, see [the example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#restricting-movement-within-an-element)

So, we can dispose our .html in this way (I hope the classnames was clear)

```
  <div #wrapper class="wrapper">
    <div #inner class="inner">
      ..what ever...
      <div *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">{{i}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="boundary">
      <div
        #indicator
        class="indicator"
        cdkDragBoundary=".boundary"
        cdkDrag
        (cdkDragMoved)="move(wrapper,indicator,inner)"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

With this .css

```
.wrapper{
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.inner{
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;  
  border:1px dotted blue;
}
.indicator{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:red;
}
.boundary{
  background-color:silver;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 30px; 
}
```

See that there're thee elements to mannage: wrapper, indicator e inner

You can have a function move like

```
  move(wrapper:HTMLElement,indicator:HTMLElement,inner:HTMLElement)
  {
    const wrapperRect=wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
    const indicatorRect=indicator.getBoundingClientRect();
    inner.scrollTop=(inner.scrollHeight-inner.clientHeight)/
                           (wrapperRect.height-indicatorRect.height)*
                           (indicatorRect.y-wrapperRect.y)
    
  }
```

NOTE: the "ecuation" is simple:

```
diff between height and scrollHeight      
------------------------------------ x pos rel indicator
     max move the indicator
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8cdlrf?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH IS IT THE SAME THING FOR THIIS QUESTION https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76563912/drag-and-scroll-on-angular